# List all directories of files which has two specif strings and located in HDFS

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I need to get all directories of files which have both  **family** and **test** as words written in the directory :

So For all directories located in :

`hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3`

I tried :

`hadoop fs -ls hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3 | grep family;test`

But it doesn't work

In fact the needed result should be like this:

`hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3/1_family_Pub_test`

`hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3/2_family_Pub_test`

`hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3/7_family_Pub_test`

`hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3/3_family_Pub_test`

`hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3/5_family_Pub_test`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

`hadoop fs -ls hdfs/rohd/data/1Ex3 | grep _family_Pub_test`